# How do I build Graphviz on a minimal Ubuntu to support the Symbol font?

Tags: ubuntu, build, docker, graphviz

I am working in a minimal Ubuntu instance — specifically, the `ubuntu:14.04` Docker image — and I want an installation of [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) that supports the Adobe Symbol font (the standard PostScript font where all the letters are Greek).

Using this dot file `greek.dot` as input:

```
digraph {
  Rock     [fontname = "Symbol"]
  Scissors [fontname = "Symbol"]
  Paper    [fontname = "Symbol"]
  Rock -> Scissors -> Paper -> Rock
}
```

If I `apt-get install graphviz` and run `dot -Tpng -o greek.png greek.dot` on this, I get:

[image]

If I instead try to build from source:

```
apt-get install -y build-essential ghostscript libpng-dev libgd-dev fontconfig

wget -O - http://graphviz.org/pub/graphviz/stable/SOURCES/graphviz-2.38.0.tar.gz | tar zxv -C /tmp && \
    cd /tmp/graphviz-2.38.0 && \
    ./configure --enable-swig=no && make && make install && \
    cd / && \
    rm -rf /tmp/graphviz-2.38.0
```

running `dot` now gives:

[image]

If I use HTML entities for the Greek letters directly:

```
digraph {
  Rock     [label = "&Rho;&omicron;ck"]
  Scissors [label = "&Sigma;cissors&invalid;"]
  Paper    [label = "Pa&pi;er"]
  Rock -> Scissors -> Paper -> Rock
}
```

(The `&invalid;` is so that we can see that GraphViz knows `&pi;` is a legitimate entity.)

With `apt-get install graphviz`, I get this:

[image]

but with the Graphviz build from source, I get:

[image]

[This page](http://graphviz.org/Download_source.php) suggests that I might need to install urw-fonts, but the link given there keeps timing out, and I'm having trouble finding this resource elsewhere.

Exactly what packages do I need to install to get Symbol to work?

Comment: I've found that doing `apt-get install libgs-dev` and rebuilding gives the same output as the prebuilt Graphviz.  The experimentation continues.

Comment: Addendum to the above: `apt-get install libpango1.0-dev` was also required, and I apparently don't understand `apt-get purge`.